# Is there a shorthand way to write 'scp' to copy back to connecting host?

Tags: command-line, ssh, scp

If I'm already remoted into a machine via SSH, is there an easy short-hand way to write an scp command that will copy the file back to the computer that is connected?

In other words, if I'm on **workstationA** and connected to a shell on **serverB**, can I just do something like:

```
scp /home/adam/somefile.txt PLACEHOLDER_FOR_WORKSTATIONA:/home/adam/myfile.txt
```

instead of having to consciously think "what's my computer's hostname/ip" and then log back into my computer that I'm already logged into?

Essentially a replacement for the `adam@workstationA:` part of `scp /home/adam/somefile.txt adam@workstationA:/home/adam/somefile.txt`?

It just seems to make it more tedious when I'm already connected to both hosts and feel like I shouldn't need to login again and waste the extra keystrokes.

Thanks

Comment: `scp /home/adam/somefile.txt $(echo $SSH_CLIENT | cut -d' ' -f1):/home/adam/myfile.txt`  should work, but won't save you any keystrokes in that form.

Comment: Just a note, you could save some typing by typing `~` instead of `/home/adam`. This *does* actually work with scp!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by creating a `config` file in your `.ssh` directory at "serverB".

Something similar to:

```
Host workstation-a
    HostName 192.168.x.x
    User adam
    Port 22
```

Now you can use `workstation-a` instead of `adam@192.168.x.x:22`. You can also use ssh keys to prevent it for asking password. It's even supports <kbd>Tab</kbd> completion you can type-in `work` then hit the <kbd>Tab</kbd> and done, it's now `workstation-a`.

---

As an alternative, you can use `sftp` too, after installing it using `sudo apt install sftp` and connecting to "serverB" you can use `get` command to retrieve the remote file and store it on the local machine.

Comment: Great tip. I really should be using keys. That would solve half my problem.  The alias will help too but doesn't fully solve my prob (me = lazy).  It seems like scp should be able to implicitly connect back to the connecting host (maybe with a CLI arg). I have several servers, and I'm often SSH'ed into them, its tedious trying to remember where I'm connected from esp if I'm moving lots of files around. Config'ing the aliases on each machine could be a hassle too. Thanks again, will mark this as answer soon if nobody posts a super-secret ssh/scp feature that solves all my problems :)